# Business Objects cannot find JDBC driver

Tags: business-objects

I have BO XI 3.1 Client Suite** installed.

I'm starting out creating an universe, but first I need to create my connection to the DB.

In this case it's a Netezza DB and I'm connecting via JDBC. I've entered the detail but when I try to test the connection I get the following error:

```
DBD: No suitable driver
```

I have the netezza jdbc driver jar on my C:\ drive. How can I point Business Objects in terms of the universe towards the class path to the driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution, to point BO to the Netezza jdbc driver (Or any other non install driver) one must edit the file:

```
jdbc.sbo
```

under dir:

```
\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\dataAccess\connectionServer\jdbc
```

Look for the appropriate lines

```
 <DataBase Active="Yes" Name="Netezza Server">
  <JDBCDriver>
    <ClassPath><Path>C:\Netezza Jar\nzjdbc3.jar</Path></ClassPath>
    <Parameter Name="JDBC Class">org.netezza.Driver</Parameter>
    <Parameter Name="URL Format">jdbc:netezza://$DATASOURCE$/$DATABASE$</Parameter>
  </JDBCDriver>
```

Replacing C:\Netezza Jar\nzjdbc3.jar with your jar location.

Hope it helps guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: did you try to add c:\ to the environment variable (Path)?